# Actualizar un documento con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Saludos comunidad.! Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación utilizando `node` y 
`mongoose` y quiero actualizar un campo especifico de un documento es decir:

Tengo un documento llamado `Libro` con una propiedad `ejemplares_disponibles` de tipo `number`, lo que deseo realizar es actualizar esa propiedad cada vez que un usuario realice el préstamo de un libro, algo así: `ejemplares_disponibles -= 1`. He intentado con el método `Libro.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {});` pero no sé como hacer para restarle **-1** a dicha propiedad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes el modelo de tu colección Libro(s) definido, una manera es hacerlo así:

```
    let libroId = req.params.libroId // el endpoint de tu API es del tipo /libros/:libroId, o sea que recibe por URL el ID del documento a actualizar

   // Primero lo buscas por su ID
   Product.findById(libroId , (err, libro) => {
     if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})

     // Aquí le restas menos uno lo que tenga ejemplares_disponibles
     libro.ejemplares_disponibles -= 1

     // Save te actualiza el documento si existe, sino, lo inserta. Pero en este caso lo actualiza porque primero lo busca
     libro.save((err, updatedLibro) => {
       if (err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al actualizar ${err}`})
       res.status(200).send( { updatedLibro} )
     })

   })
```

Básicamente, primero lo buscas por su ID, luego modifica el atributo deseado y por último lo actualizas.

Comment: Gracias amigo con eso lo pude lograr.!

Comment: @DarwinQuiroz por nada :p